# Rails function or property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a bit confused by the following Ruby function definition. Am I declaring a function or a property of the object?

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name)
end
```

If I'm declaring a function, how does `project_params` know to `return` the result? I'm used to the contents being evaluated, but here it seems like Rails returns the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby does not have *properties*. Objects only have (externally) *methods*, and all methods in Ruby will return the value of the last statement, unless you explicitly `return`.

Ruby does have *instance variables*, such as `@foo` and `@bar`, however these are only accessed internally. They are simply variables with their scope set the the instance. Class variables, eg: `@@foobar` are scoped to the class.

There is some good information about Ruby methods in the [Ruby Programming Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Method_Calls).

Happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

Ruby automatically returns the result of the last executed expression in a method.

Comment: very interesting... and so this is a function, not an object property it seems. From the docs, it looks like Ruby doesn't have "object properties" that are declared seperately, it just has instance variables. 

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_object_oriented.htm

Does that mean you can't have static properties of an object?

Comment: Yes, this is a function. Although, the correct ruby term would be a "method".  I don't think the term "property" is ever used in ruby. There are a couple of concepts that can be called "a property": readers, writers, instance variables... I don't know what language you're coming from, but may be this will shed some light: http://www.sitepoint.com/properties-and-methods-in-ruby-from-a-net-pov/

Comment: You sure can. "static" property would simply be an instance variable on the class of an object. But to access it, you would create a reader method. It's not really a topic for comments. May be you should read a book on ruby/rails. Michael Hartls' rails tutorial is the first thing that comes to mind: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Comment: Thanks so much for the help & politeness (most people can be harsh on SO with new language questions). I'm coming from PHP + JS background, and I will check out those resources.

Comment: No problem. Take care.